# Wordpress categories hierarchy

Tags: wordpress, hierarchy, categories

I can't seem to find out why this code doesn't output the categories in hierarchy:

```
<ul>
<?php  
$args = array(
    'show_option_all'    => '',
    'container'           => false, 
    'orderby'            => 'name',
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'         => 0,
    'use_desc_for_title' => 0,
    'child_of'           => 0,
    'hierarchical'       => 1,
    'number'             => null,
    'echo'               => 1,
    'depth'              => -1,
    'taxonomy'           => 'category'

); 
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '(' . $category->count . ')</a></li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

Instead all the list items are outputting as parents like this...

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://test.dev/category/media/">Media(1)</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://test.dev/category/media/movies/">Movies(1)</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://test.dev/category/media/tv-shows/">TV Shows(1)</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://test.dev/category/uncategorised/">Uncategorised(1)</a></li>
</ul>
```

...but they should be like this...

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://test.dev/category/media/">Media(1)</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://test.dev/category/media/movies/">Movies(1)</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://test.dev/category/media/tv-shows/">TV Shows(1)</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://wordpress.dev/category/uncategorised/">Uncategorised(1)</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see 'hierarchical' is set to 1, but it doesn't work as expected.

PS: I can't use the standard wp_list_categories method (http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) because I will need to be able to customise the markup in the list.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Run print_r($categories) after setting up the categories query.  That should give you a better idea of how the $categories array is structured. The loop that you have right now doesn't treat the different levels of the hierarchy differently.

Comment: you must create recursive function with foreach loop. same as: if(has_child) getChilds()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use following code:

```
<ul>
<?php  
$args = array(
    'show_option_all'    => '',
    'container'           => false,
    'orderby'            => 'name',
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'         => 0,
    'use_desc_for_title' => 0,
    'child_of'           => 0,
    'hierarchical'       => 1,
    'number'             => null,
    'echo'               => 1,
    'depth'              => -1,
    'taxonomy'           => 'category'

);
$categories = get_categories( $args );  
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {  
    if($category->parent==0)
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '(' . $category->count . ')</a></li>';
    else
    echo '<ul><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '(' . $category->count . ')</a></li></ul>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE**

```
$args = array(

    'hide_empty'         => 0,
    'echo'               => 1,
    'taxonomy'           => 'category',
    'hierarchical'  =>1,
    'show_count' => 1,

);

function add_class_wp_list_categories($wp_list_categories) {
        $pattern = '/<li class="/is';
        $replacement = '<li class="first ';
        return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $wp_list_categories);
}
add_filter('wp_list_categories','add_class_wp_list_categories');

echo wp_list_categories( $args );
```

Comment: Woah that's close thanks. The hierarchy is there but the markup is a little muddled up. See here: http://pastie.org/9753414

Comment: see update. You can simply do using wp_list_categories.

Comment: Thanks again but I can't do it that way. In my original post I said I can't use the wp_list_categories method because I need to be able to customise the markup :-(

Comment: What exactly you want to customize? you can customize using walker

Comment: I want to add classes and other elements into the <li> elements. How would I do this with categories with walker?

Comment: you add class using add_filter.I have updated above check again

Comment: Hi Bhumi (and others), this looks great I was hoping you might be able to advise how I show this only for terms used in the post this list appears on? Currently this shows all available terms within the taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'orderby' => 'parent'

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'your_tax',
    'orderby' => 'parent'
);
$cats = get_categories($args);
```